# How do I specify a minimum ram requirement for my app

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, device, ram

I plan on making a mobile game for both IOS and Android devices. I noticed there are a lot of android devices that have certain ram installed. My plan is to have people download my game within at least 2gb of ram. But anything lower than that, they cannot download. I want to make this game for android players who has enough ram to play. Any way I can set this up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is that there is no way to achieve this by using manifest filters, rather you can specify the minimum amount of ram required in the google play console when you select which devices to target.

See here for an up to date guide https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455

Scroll down on the above link to the part that says "Exclude your app from certain devices" and then expand the tab that says "Manage excluded devices by performance indicators"

There it explains how to narrow down devices by ram or chipset

Comment: But won't this be able to classify the ram needed for an app?

Comment: yes it will, but its done in the play console, not in the manifest